# Stream Collections Error and understanding

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

I'm trying to read in a CSV using java 8's `Stream` API and create a matrix from it.

This is mainly to learn `Stream`s (there are of course other ways to do this without `Stream`s).

Here is the code:

```
public class MatrixCreator {

    public static Function<String, List<Double>> mapLineToListOfDoubles = (line) -> {
        String [] elements = line.split(",\\s*");
        return Arrays.stream(elements).map((String stringElement) -> Double.parseDouble(stringElement)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    };

    //Error from this -- listed below
    public static Collector<List<Double>, List<Double>, List<Double>> listCollector = Collector.of(ArrayList<Double>::new, List<Double>::addAll, (ArrayList<Double> left, List<Double> right) -> {
        left.addAll(right);
        return left;
    });


    /**
     * Creates a matrix from the specified file.
     * @param filePath Path to CSV, matrix, file
     */
    public static Matrix createMatrix(String filePath) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        List<Double> x = bufferedReader.lines().map(mapLineToListOfDoubles).collect(listCollector);
        return null;  // for the moment.
    }
}
```

The following error is given:

```
Error:(26, 96) java: no suitable method found for of(ArrayList<[...]::new,List<Doubl[...]ddAll,(ArrayList[...]ft; })
    method java.util.stream.Collector.<T,R>of(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,T>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<R>,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
        inferred: java.util.List<java.lang.Double>
        equality constraints(s): java.util.List<java.lang.Double>,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>)
    method java.util.stream.Collector.<T,A,R>of(java.util.function.Supplier<A>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<A,T>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<A>,java.util.function.Function<A,R>,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,A,R
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Clearly Java cannot determine the method to use, but I cannot determine where to go from here.

I'd appreciate any help regarding the reason for this error.

Comment: You are making your life unnecessary hard. You can simply omit the types from the lambda parameters saving a lot of boilerplate writing and remove the error at the same time: `(left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }`. The same applies to the method  references: you don’t need to write `ArrayList<Double>::new` or `List<Double>::addAll`. Just `ArrayList::new` or `List::addAll` is enough. Use the power of Java 8’s type inference. And you can replace `(String stringElement) -> Double.parseDouble(stringElement)` with `Double::parseDouble`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only [Collector.of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) method that can match the number of arguments you supplied is :

```
static <T,R> Collector<T,R,R>   of(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,T> accumulator, BinaryOperator<R> combiner, Collector.Characteristics... characteristics)
```

You declare the return type to be `Collector<List<Double>, List<Double>, List<Double>>`, so both `T` and `R` are `List<Double>`.

However, in your arguments list, the combiner (the 3rd argument) receives a lambda expression with two parameters `ArrayList<Double> left` and `List<Double> right` that returns an `ArrayList<Double>`. But the method signature expects a `BinaryOperator<R>` which means both parameters + the return value of the lambda expression must be of the same type.

I suggest you change your code to :

```
public static Collector<List<Double>, List<Double>, List<Double>> listCollector = Collector.of(ArrayList<Double>::new, List<Double>::addAll, (List<Double> left, List<Double> right) -> {
    left.addAll(right);
    return left;
});
```

I'm not sure if that's the only problem (I can't test it), but there's a good chance it is, since that's what the error message you get from the compiler implies :

```
  (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: java.util.List<java.lang.Double>
    equality constraints(s): java.util.List<java.lang.Double>,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>)
```

The remainder of the error message is irrelevant, since the other `Collector.of` method expects an additional argument, and therefore is not relevant to your code.

Comment: absolutely. makes sense! Didn't notice that little bit. Thank you!